# sourceTree isn't letting me push to gitHub after supposedly typing my passcode wrong once

Tags: github, xcode8, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

sourceTree isn't letting me push to gitHub after supposedly typing my passcode wrong once and now when I try to push to that remote it won't let me even after I deleted that remote and added it again. Here is the error Pushing to https://github.com/user/app.git
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user/app.git/'
Thanks for any help in advance!!!
P.S. "user" and "app" are not the real names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `Sourcetree`, `git-push` is failing due to invalid credentials.
 Just try to re-setup your git credentials again as explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/).